# whoami command is showing different user name in jenkins cli and linux cli although workspace i

Tags: linux, jenkins, command-line-interface, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzLWV.png)Hi All,

"whoami" command is showing as different user. when I am giving this command in jenkins cli it is showing as **jenkins** but in the same workspace when I am giving this command in linux CLI it is showing as **lokeshk**.I have followed many forum, link and community in the internet but still I am facing this issue. I have attached screenshot please have a look.Any leads will be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEiza.png)

Comment: It doesn't actually know who is typing the command.  It is only reporting the username of the process.  The jenkins cli must be running as user jenkins.

Comment: jenkins cli is running as user jenkins only but in the sameworkspace linux cli is showing user as lokeshk

Comment: In fact, if you run `ps -ef` you will see many processes with different users.

Comment: Thats true but if we are using same workspace it should show same user right? I think it doesnt matter if we are using whoami cli through cli or jenkins cli.

Comment: I do not believe that there is any concept of a workspace in the process table.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot link please check it once dont know why in the same workspace it is showing as different user.

Comment: @LokeshKumar: Does the answer help resolve your doubt?

Answer (score 0):

While installing `jenkins`, by default it creates a user with name `jenkins` and all operations get executed under same user. So, when you are using jenkins-cli to check `whoami`, it shows `jenkins` user.

Seeing your attached screeshot, I believe you logged in to linux-cli with `lokeshk` user so when you check for `whoami` in linux-cli it is showing `lokeshk` user.

Note: `whoami` command is used to print the loggedin user name, irrespective of the workspace where you are right now and by whom it was created.

Example:

Lets assume a system have two users `user1` and `user2`. `user1` created a directory named `user1_dir`. If you loggin with `user2` and perform `whoami` in `user1_dir`(or anywhere), it will result in `user2` as `user2` is the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand it using example. I am using CentOS 7. If you have installed Jenkins using all defaults, it will create a user `jenkins`. You can check it using:

```
[centos@infra ~]$ grep jenkins /etc/passwd
jenkins:x:996:993:Jenkins Automation Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false
```

Now, if you run a Jenkins job, it will display output similar to the following:

[image]

As you can see above, i ran two commands, `ps -ef` and `whoami`. We can see that Jenkins application is running as user `jenkins`. Output of `whoami` is also `jenkins`.

Now, i logged into the machine as user `centos`. You can see that by the output shown below:

```
[centos@infra ~]$ whoami
centos
```

Switching directory *doesn't* affect the output of `whoami`

```
[centos@infra ~]$ pwd
/home/centos
[centos@infra ~]$ whoami
centos
[centos@infra ~]$ cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/job-a
[centos@infra job-a]$ whoami
centos
```

Now, if i want to see the same output on command line for `whoami` as i am seeing in the Jenkins log, then i will first have to *switch* to `jenkins` user. Since `jenkins`, by default, is configured to run as a `service account`, no shell (`/bin/false`) is assigned to it as you can see in the first output above. Just to clear your doubt, i will change the shell to `/bin/bash` temporarily.

```
[centos@infra job-a]$ sudo vim /etc/passwd
[centos@infra job-a]$ grep jenkins /etc/passwd
jenkins:x:996:993:Jenkins Automation Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash
```

Now if i try to switch to `jenkins` user and observe the output of `whoami`, you will see what you *wanted* to see. :)

```
[centos@infra job-a]$ sudo su - jenkins
Last login: Sat May 30 09:48:56 UTC 2020 on pts/0
-bash-4.2$ whoami
jenkins
-bash-4.2$ cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/job-a
-bash-4.2$ whoami
jenkins
```

Hope that clears your doubt.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot .I am able to do it whatever I wanted. Really appreciate your answer the way you have explained. Again thanks a lot..:)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :) You may consider upvoting/marking it as an answer. Kindly go through this link, in case you're not aware how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers